# Identifying breaker and wire size - 208-240 VAC | 11 KW | 48 amps | 1 phase

Tags: wiring, circuit-breaker

I'm wiring a steam generator for my shower and I'm not sure of what I'll need. Here are the specs:

**INPUT VOLTAGE** : 208-240 VAC

**KW RATING** : 11

**AMPS** : 48

**PHASE** : 1

Run 240V Power source to the generator

Wire sizes recommended by NEC (2002 Version). Minimum wire temperature rating 90°C. Type THHN.

Does that add up to needed a 60amp double pole breaker to deliver 240 volts with a 4 AGW wire? I assume 60 amp breaker since the machine uses 48 amps and you can only use up to 80% of the capacity.

Comment: Sounds right, but check the cost with 2 gauge aluminum if it will fit in the breaker.  Might be cheaper than copper depending on distance.  Think you might be able to use the minimum of 6 gauge copper/4 gauge AL also, but bigger is usually better.

Comment: Read the installation instructions, don't just do a simple calculation based on your understanding. For example,  our GE range is rated 10.0 kW at 208 V and 13.3 kW at 240 V, but the installation instructions recommend/allow a 40 A double pole breaker. The required breaker for your bathroom "steam generator" might not be based on a simple calculation of derated maximum power. I find it hard to believe that any consumer appliance like that would require a 60 A breaker.

Comment: @Jim ranges are weird, though, they heavily consider demand factors.  (all burners won't be at 100% duty cycle all the time).  Heaters on the other hand take a 125% derate.

Comment: @Harper, yeah nobody has all 4 surface burners on max and the oven on high broil at the same time, but a "bathroom steam generator" might pull full power continuously. What do the the instructions say?

Comment: Is the 11 kW rating at 208 V or at 240 V? I presume you have 240 V, right? Be sure the instructions don't specify two independent 2-pole breakers which total 60 A (electric tankless water heaters usually do specificy two or three 40 A 2-pole breakers serving independent heating elements). What part of the country is this being installed in? How cold is inlet water?

Comment: Thanks for the comments. The instructions are pretty scarce on the electrical requirements. They do not specify a different kW rating for 208 vs 240 V. It just says "Input Voltage 208-240VAC. Run 240V Power source to the generator." I just noticed it also says "Wire sizes recommended by NEC (2002 Version). Minimum wire temperature rating 90°C. Type THHN." which I missed before. I'm not familiar with THHN, how is that different from NMD?

Comment: THHN wire is individual wire that meets a certain standard of being rated to operate at up to 90 deg C. in dry locations and is used in conduit. It sounds like the instructions are assuming that the wires supplying power to this device will be in conduit rather than NM cable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Certain loads *including heaters* require a 125% derate, so take 48A and multiply by 125%.  That will give 60A right on the button.   This builder knew what they were doing. You need an actual 60A circuit.

An *actual* 60A circuit requires:

- 4 AWG Type NM or UF cable
- 6 AWG "any other type" copper wire or cable if the terminals are rated 75°C
- 4 AWG "any other type" aluminum wire or cable if 75°C and rated for aluminum

This is not to be confused with a 55A circuit using #6 NM/UF cable.  That circuit is allowed to use a 60A breaker because 55A breakers are not made, but that is *still* a 55A circuit and inadequate for a 60A provisioning (48A heater).

Comment: Given the machine is using 48 amps, is there a benefit to use 4 gauge instead of 6?

Comment: @AfterWorkGuinness There's an advantage to larger wire if you're going a long distance, but if you are, then find a place for a subpanel nearby and run 2-2-2-4 aluminum to the subpanel. Huge savings and nothing wrong with it as subpanel feeder. If you're using NM or UF, one advantage of #4 is the inspector won't red-flag it and make you tear it out. LOL.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Finally got hold of the inspector and they said #6 was fine for this application.